# How to use an InputDialog inside EMF Commands?

Tags: java, dialog, eclipse-emf

I am trying to open an InputDialog inside the execute() method of a custom command. It looks as follows:

```
public class MyCommand extends CompoundCommand{
   ...
   execute(){
      try {
         ...
         super.execute();
      }catch(Exception e){
         InputDialog myDialog = ...
         myDialog.open();
         ...
         super.execute();
      }
   }
}
```

It works fine but it throws some exceptions. These are:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: While executing the operation, 
an exception occurred
```

which is caused by

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot open an operation while one 
is already open
```

I am overriding the createSetCommand() method of a ItemProvider in my EMF project. The input dialog is necessary in order to get the valid value from the user in case he/she entered a wrong value.

Thanx Alot Before Hand,
KanAfghan

Comment: a) could you please show us how you are creating the InputDialog please?
b) you should validate the user-input preferably in createCommand(), and possibly even a CommandWrapper instead of a CompoundCommand (unless you know what you are doing).

Comment: It is not relevant any more. I used a totally different approach than presented above since this approach is not the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Nice work KanAfghan. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a totally different approach than presented above since this approach is not the correct way of doing it.